# Cannot find explicit intent, android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I am trying to navigate from one page to another:

MyAdapter -> ShowArticle

But the above error is being thrown, I have added the below to the manifest; but is still not working. Am I doing something wrong with the activity I have put into the manifest?

How I am navigating:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent = new Intent(context, ShowArticle.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The manifest declaration:

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.rssApplication.ShowArticle" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.rssApplication.MyAdapter"
        >
     <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.rssApplication.MyAdapter" />  
</activity>
```

LOG CAT:

```
    07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.rssapplication/com.example.rssapplication.ShowArticle}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1647)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at com.example.rssapplication.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:84)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-17 14:07:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22694):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Callum

UPDATE:

I have foud the solution, thanks to the comments left below.

1) In the manifest I was declaring he activity twice. Remove the meta-date tag along with its contents.
2) I was exending ListActivity, as opposed to activity. I extended activity and it works fine.

Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: see the difference in case "rssApplication" and "rssapplication"

Comment: package name and class name are case sensitive. rssApplication vs rssapplication

Comment: It's not the problem, but you're instantiating Intent two times with no need.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not solve the problem; the same errors are coming up.